# ActiveAdmin and "uninitialized constant InheritedResources::Base"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin, inherited-resources

I'm just trying ActiveAdmin. I've got the dashboard and some resources working, but now when I run for example a rails generator I got:

```
% rails generate scaffold Post name:string
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant InheritedResources::Base (NameError)
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@lap/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/base_controller/menu.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@lap/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/base_controller/menu.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@lap/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/base_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@lap/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/actions.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@lap/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/actions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@lap/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/resource_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@lap/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/batch_actions.rb:7:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@lap/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/event.rb:25:in `call'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@lap/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/event.rb:25:in `block in dispatch'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@lap/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/event.rb:24:in `each'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@lap/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/event.rb:24:in `dispatch'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@lap/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:179:in `load!'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@lap/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:205:in `routes'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@lap/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin.rb:79:in `routes'
    from .../lap-app/config/routes/routes.rb:27:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@lap/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
    ...
```

And `routes.rb:27` is:

```
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

I found nothing that's working for me :((

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you accidentally registered something that isn't a model (using rails g active_admin:resource NAME)? ActiveAdmin.routes(self) auto-generates CRUD routes for your registered resources so there's a chance one of those registered resources actually isn't one.

If you want to register a page for something that isn't a model and you've already registered it replace ActiveAdmin.register NAME with ActiveAdmin.register_page "NAME" in the .rb

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)` to the top instead of in the mid or at the end of the `routes.rb` file.